# DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate ComboBox not show until clicked twice

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a 
`DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate` 
column in a `DataGrid`. What's happening is I can see the selected item but not as a `ComboBox` until I clicked it twice to enable Editing.

Basically, I want it to behave like a `CellTemplate` but is editable like `CellEditingTemplate`. How can I achieve this?

I prefer a solution in `Xaml` rather than in code.

I have tried setting `Style.Trigger` for `DataGridCell` like below

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Also tried setting the ComboBox IsEditable property to True

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Material" MinWidth="100">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Material,Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference MaterialDef}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The code is very simple

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="200" Header="Material" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox MinWidth="200" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Material,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" DisplayMemberPath="Code" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference Materials}}" Margin="2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to set both `CellEditingTemplate` and `CellTemplate`. Like below:

`

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="200" Header="Material" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox MinWidth="200" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Material,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" DisplayMemberPath="Code" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference Materials}}" Margin="2" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox MinWidth="200" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=Material,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" DisplayMemberPath="Code" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference Materials}}" Margin="2" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

`

You can also have the `DataTemplate` in the resource and reference to it.